# Run Rails commands outside of console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, console

With my large application, the Rails console takes a while to load up. Is there a way to single commands more easily?

I'd also like to be able to automate stuff, and `echo "query" | rails console` isn't a great way to do things.

Thoughts?

EDIT: What about a long-running process that I can ping queries to whenever I have need?

Comment: I'm curious what your use case for this is, as it seems that there's probably a better solution.

Comment: I'm using Geckoboard to grab stats from a running application, using a JSON feed I'm setting up with these queries... am I doing it completely wrong?

Comment: It would probably make more sense to just build this code right into your app and grab the data over HTTP. If it's sensitive info, then require some sort of authorization, e.g. an API key with the request.

Comment: I, unfortunately, don't have much experience at all with Rails. I'd have no idea how to build a query like `User.all.count` into a page and grab the results. How should I do that?

Comment: Well if you're trying to make a JSON feed, then you would just generate it as JSON. There are plenty of resources for how to send a JSON response using Rails.

Comment: How would I add it to the app though?

Comment: If you don't know how to do that, then perhaps you need to work through a Rails tutorial or the Rails Guides. It's a rather broad question.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

There are two main ways to run commands outside console:

1. Rake task which depends on :environment
2. rails runner (previously script/runner), eg:

   ```
   $ rails runner "query"
   ```

Both are pretty well documented on the rails guide: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#bin-rails-runner

Both of these methods will still take the same time as a console to fire up, but they are useful for non-interactive tasks.

Answer (score 47):

Just pipe it in:

```
echo 'puts Article.count' | bundle exec rails c
```

It should now be a lot faster than when then the question was originally asked, because of [Spring](https://github.com/rails/spring). It's not immediate, but still a lot faster than spinning up the whole app. Use this for the fast lane, it should run in under a second (assuming your required command is fast):

```
echo 'puts Article.count' | spring rails c
```

If you really want a single long-running process, you could easily do it by creating a controller action that simply runs whatever you POST to it, then send commands to it using curl behind an alias. The action would of course be completely insecure and should be triple-guarded against running anywhere near production, but it would be easy to setup.

Comment: Genius!! Btw, if you're trying to return a "fail exit code" you use `abort`. For example: `echo 'abort' | bundle exec rails c && echo 'Success!'` will not show `Success!` in the console where as `echo 'exit' | bundle exec rails c && echo 'Success!'` will show `Success!`.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**: `bundle exec` command allows us to run an executable script in the specific context of the project's bundle - making all gems specified in the `Gemfile` available to require in Ruby application. In addition it eventually avoids any conflicts with other versions of rake installed globally.

```
echo '<command>' | bundle exec rails c
```

for more information look at the documentation of [bundler](https://bundler.io/man/bundle-exec.1.html)

**example**:

```
configuration_item=$(echo 'ConfigurationManager.getKey("authentication_method")' | bundle exec rails c )
echo $configuration_item

#output:
MFA_authentication
```